# java8 - map a list of a list: check if nested list is null

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Consider this object:

```
final List<ApplicationUser> output = Arrays.asList(

    new ApplicationUser() {

        @Override
        public List<Role> getAssociationRoles() {
            //return null;
            return Arrays.listOf(...);              
        }


    }
);

public interface Role {
    String getId();
}
```

I want to return a List of Role::id.

The snippet below works if *getAssociationRoles* is not null

```
final List<String> rolesId = applicationUsers
            .stream()
            .map(ApplicationUser::getAssociationRoles)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .map(Role::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hovever a **NullPointerException** is thrown if *getAssociationRoles* is null.

How can I prevent this ?

Comment: Just fix `getAssociationRoles()` to never return `null`. Use `Collections.emptyList()` as default value.

Comment: @Holger  The first thing that came to my mind after reading `getAssociationRoles()`. That should be the actual answer to the question.

Comment: @Holger what if the object is not in my domain ?

Comment: The rule that collections should not be `null` is a universal one. Violating it is bad coding style. You may send a bug report to whoever is responsible for the method. Besides that, you have an answer that shows how to deal with such bad methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `filter` to filter out the null association roles:

```
final List<String> rolesId = applicationUsers
    .stream()
    .map(ApplicationUser::getAssociationRoles)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) <------- here!
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(Role::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: A better [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817502/java8-map-a-list-of-a-list-check-if-nested-list-is-null#comment102066116_57817502).